# Как занести значение Y в память?

Tags: sasm

Разработать программу вычисления функции y = f( a, b, c, d, e). Формат данных – двойное слово.
Значения аргументов a, b, c, d, e задать в программе.
Результат y в память

```
%include "io.inc"

section .DATA
    a: dd 10
    b: dd 15
    c: dd 150
    d: dd 10
    e: dd 250
    y: dd 0

section .text
    global CMAIN
CMAIN:
    mov ebp, esp; for correct debugging
    ;write your code here
    MOV EAX, 0
    MOV EAX, [a]      ; A в AX
    MOV EBX, [b]      ; B в BX
    IMUL EBX         ;A*B в EAX
    MOV ECX,EAX     ;Перенос в ECX
    MOV EAX,[c]      ;C в AX
    MOV EBX,[d]      ;D в BX
    IDIV EBX         ;Делим C на D
    ADD EAX,ECX     ;Прибавляем к EAX ECX
    MOV EBX,[e]     ;Переносим E в EBX
    SUB EAX, EBX       ;Y=A*B+C/D-E  
    PRINT_DEC 4, eax
    
    xor eax, eax
    ret
```

Comment: `Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.`

Comment: `error: C:\Users\kkk\AppData\Local\Temp\SASM\program.o: No such file or directory`

Comment: `mismatch in operand sizes`

Comment: У меня [здесь](https://www.mycompiler.io/view/1p3CDuiDXfi) работает.

Comment: а как вы задаете y?

Comment: Оно и [без dword работает](https://www.mycompiler.io/view/3BaIIR4EgEn)

Comment: а у вас еще и двоеточие стоит, а если без него?

Comment: наверное это не предусмотрено, завтра у преподавателя спрошу.

Answer (score 0):

Ну я занес в у после `ret`. Не знаю, как потом оттуда вытащить переменную. Но задание считаю выполненным.

```
%include "io.inc"

section .DATA
    a: dd 1010b
    b: dd 15
    c: dd 150
    d: dd 10
    e: dd 250
    y: dd 0

section .text
    global CMAIN
CMAIN:
    mov ebp, esp; for correct debugging
    ;write your code here
    MOV AX, 0
    MOV AL, [a]      ; A в AX
    MOV BL, [b]      ; B в BX
    IMUL BL         ;A*B в EAX
    MOV CX,AX     ;Перенос в ECX
    MOV AL,[c]      ;C в AX
    MOV BL,[d]      ;D в BX
    IDIV BL         ;Делим C на D
    ADD AX,CX     ;Прибавляем к EAX ECX
    MOV BX,[e]     ;Переносим E в EBX
    SUB AX, BX      ;Y=A*B+C/D-E
    xor eax, eax
    ret
    MOV [y],AX
```

Comment: неверно, нужно после SUB.